# Fancybox Confirmation Window

Tags: jquery, fancybox, newsletter, confirmation, onsubmit

I have a newsletter sign-up form and I'd like the confirmation to appear in a Fancybox window. Trouble is, I don't know how to do this! What code do I use to call the window onSubmit? Where do I put the code for the window when it's not in use? Should it be its own webpage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this [simple tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial) will help you out. See demo [here](http://www.queness.com/resources/html/modal/jquery-modal-window.html).

[This one](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqDialog) may really help you out. See the demo [here](http://kailashnadh.name/code/jqdialog/).

Also check this tuts out:

http://www.deviantpoint.com/post/2009/03/12/Using-jQuery-UI-Dialogs-for-confirmation-windows.aspx

Comment: Alright, maybe I deserved that. Point taken, you snarky bastard.